# How to Mointor queue(s) and send data from Nifi to prometheus?

Tags: docker, apache-nifi, prometheus

Basically, I want to monitor a failure queue(s) and if the count increases a threshold, I want to create an Alert.

1) The queues can be more than one.

2) The Alert: I want to send the data to Prometheus from where I'll read and display in Alerta.

I'm confused as there seem many ways and I don't know what the correct or best way. I followed this https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/172092/monitoring-nifi-back-pressure-threshold-and-trigge.html
for queue monitoring which works for a single queue but still, the Prometheus part is left.

Secondly, I read there are **ReportingTasks** in Nifi which can do something similar and report the matrices. e.g SiteToSiteStatusReportingTask

I'm not sure which approach to choose ReportingTask, create custom ReportingTask or the normal NIfi Workflow to monitor as in the article.

And Secondly how to send data to Prometheus. Some PostProcessor or again a reporting task or custom processor etc??

How would you tackle this and whats a good approach?

Answer (score 3):

## Update for NiFi 1.10.0 (November 2019)

NiFi now includes a Prometheus Reporting Task that can be added and configured via the top-level hamburger menu. Enabling this creates a `/metrics` endpoint on the configured port that Prometheus can be configures to scrape to pull metrics.

---

## Original answer (pre NiFi 1.10.0)

Prometheus typically works by scraping other applications/services periodically to pull metrics. The monitored application (typically a web service) exposes an HTTP endpoint that returns metrics in the Prometheus format.

When instrumenting the application directly so that Prometheus can scrape it is not possible, the [Prometheus Pushgateway](https://prometheus.io/docs/instrumenting/pushing/) is an alternative. See also the [best practices documentation](https://prometheus.io/docs/practices/pushing/).

So you have a few options for your approach. One viable approach that I would recommend exploring would be:

```
NiFi ReportingTask > ??? > Pushgateway > Prometheus
```

Where `???` is your custom implementation that bridges the metrics written to NiFi's ReportingTask interface into the Pushgateway. This might just be a custom ReportingTask implementation that provides the bridge, or it might be a sequence of smaller steps, such as:

- `ReportingTask > file on disk > Pushgateway > ...`
- `ReportingTask > JMX > Pushgateway > ...`

I know others in the NiFi community have (or are actively) looking into this same capability. I recommend you take a look at:

- [NIFI-4362](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NIFI-4362) on the Apache NiFi JIRA
- [nifi-prometheus-reporter](https://github.com/mkjoerg/nifi-prometheus-reporter) on GitHub.
- This [question](https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/157929/how-to-enable-apache-nifi-metrics-for-jmx.html) on Hortonworks Community Connection might also be helpful.

Another approach would be to implement a NiFi Extension that provides a custom implementation of a ReportingTask and also runs a webserver exposing a port/endpoint that Prometheus can scrape directly without using a Pushgateway. The `PrometheusReportingTask` would collect metrics written to the ReportingTask interface and map them to the Prometheus data model using the Prometheus Java client library. The `PrometheusReportingTask` would also provide a scrape endpoing that dumps the in-memory prometheus metrics to the prometheus text wire format. There are various open source implementations of Prometheus scrape targets you could look at, such as the [Actuator Prometheus Endpoint](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-actuator/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/actuate/metrics/export/prometheus/PrometheusScrapeEndpoint.java), which integrates Prometheus with a [Micrometer Prometheus Meter Registry](https://github.com/micrometer-metrics/micrometer).

Comment: Is it possible with some processor(s) to create an HTTP endpoint in the format which Prometheus pull model works with? e.g. HandleHTTPResponse etc.  Why to use push model in this case?

Also what I understood from the [nifi-prometheus-reporter] (https://github.com/mkjoerg/nifi-prometheus-reporter/issues) its only has limited matrices. I want to monitor queues e.g. backpressure, which it doesn't. 

I'm, not an expert, I'm new so I'm confused with all the options JMX etc. There's no one recommended/defined way.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. You could probably find a way to do it with processors. There is ListenHTTP, but what it does internally os start an HTTP server on a different port, which is why I suggested doing that in the reporting task impl, as then it would always be available when that reporting task is used and not rely on additional processors in your flow. I recommended push just because it seems like the easiest way to get started using the PushGateway, but there is no functional advantage. Fair point regarding limitations of Prometheus-reporter. I’ll update my answer to include that

Comment: Ok i tried. nifi-prometheus-reporter on github which uses pushgateway and integrated this (https://github.com/apache/nifi/pull/3257) PR which uses Promethus usual pull method. 

But they both send generic metrics I want to send some custom. Like, generate an alert when a certain threshold is reached. 
(https://community.hortonworks.com/articles/83610/nifi-rest-api-flowfile-count-monitoring.html)
Was trying to do something like this but instead of putmail send data to promethus where i can generate alert.

Comment: Adding instrumentation of custom metric types to NiFi is something that I'm interested in as well, but to be honest is a bit outside my knowledge currently. I only know the reporting tasks are how you can change the destination of metrics that are already instrumented.

Answer (score 2):

Prometheus reporting task is available in [Apache Nifi 1.10](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/NIFI/Release+Notes#ReleaseNotes-Version1.10.0) (November 4th, 2019)